# How to migrate a Maven based web application POM to use Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, migration, build.gradle, maven-plugin

Yes, yes, I know! There are hundreds of Maven-to-Gradle related questions here on SO, but none of them, AFAICT addresses the inherent difficulties (of a constantly moving target [Gradle!]) of porting a very simple Maven POM to use Gradle for compilation.

In this particular case, we have an app the original developers are relying on using the GWT plugin for Eclipse, but that many other developers would like to use something more modern and less bloated, i.e. *Gradle*. All sources simply brush this off to, *`"you can simply convert pom.xml in Gradle"`*, as is [stated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html) in the Gradle documentation, unfortunately **this is simply not working for most practical purposes**.

The project under consideration is [circuitJS1](https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1) which was ported to use Maven [here](https://github.com/briangordon/circuitjs1). The resulting **`pom.xml`** reads:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lushprojects.circuitjs1</groupId>
    <artifactId>circuitjs</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.15</version>
    <packaging>gwt-app</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- generating dependency report is slow; disable it -->
        <dependency.locations.enabled>false</dependency.locations.enabled>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId> <!-- artifact with sources is easier to handle during development -->
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- declaring only in order to skip during site deployment -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <siteDirectory>site</siteDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration><!-- we don't need those reports; disabling speeds up 
                        build -->
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- gwt compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-rc-9</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <moduleName>com.lushprojects.circuitjs1.circuitjs1</moduleName>
                    <!-- this is the best setting for a laptop with 2 cores and HT -->
                    <localWorkers>0.5C</localWorkers>
                    <warName>circuitjs</warName>
                    <optimize>9</optimize>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>-style</compilerArg>
                        <compilerArg>PRETTY</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <codeServerPort>8888</codeServerPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- copy a few things around before packaging the website -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>war</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}-${project.version}/circuitjs1</directory>
                                    <targetPath>circuitjs1</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Cloning that repository and simply doing: `mvn install` will give you a working (circuit simulation) website, that you can open with your browser, under the file location:
`file:///C:/path/to/circuitjs1/target/site/circuitjs.html`

However, using `gradle init --type pom` to convert to Gradle, yield a **`build.gradle`** like this:

```
/* This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task. */
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.8.2'
}
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from(sourceSets.main.allJava)
}

group = 'com.lushprojects.circuitjs1'
version = '2.1.15'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
            artifact(sourcesJar)
        }
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Unfortunately, using that with `gradle build`, doesn't seem to yield anything that can be ran in the browser. It does generate `./build/` directory but which contents are not of any use at all.

```
build
├── classes
│   └── java
│       └── main
│           └── com
├── generated
│   └── sources
│       └── annotationProcessor
│           └── java
├── libs
│   └── circuitjs-2.1.15.jar
└── tmp
    ├── compileJava
    └── jar
        └── MANIFEST.MF
```

I have also tried to beat this file into shape by adding things like:

```
//id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '2.2.1'
id 'java'
id 'maven'
//id 'gwt-maven'
id 'maven-publish'
id 'war'
//id 'org.metahelicase.site-builder' version '1.1'
//id 'org.jbake.site' version '5.0.0'
//id 'gradle.site' version '0.6'
//id 'com.stehno.gradle.webpreview' version '0.3.0'
```

But to no avail...

---

- **How can I make this `build.gradle` script work correctly to produce the web files necessary to run the application locally in my browser?**
- Are there any up-to-date tools available that can do this for you?

Comment: "insists on using Eclipse" I don't get the connection to Eclipse...

Comment: Not much, just that they use the GWT plugin for it and that there are other options available. Made a slight edit.

Comment: Any specific reasons you want to move to Gradle?

Comment: Many, to mention juts a few, faster, more efficient, better documented, better support, wide spread use? However, I don't see your question being relevant.

Comment: I was just curious. Migrating from Maven to Gradle is not trivial, and Maven is by far the most popular build tool, so I was genuinly interested why you chose to switch. In terms of build speed, Gradle has probably some advantages.

Comment: Actually it turned out to be too trivial! The problem (as always) is lacking documentation (or links to it).  The Maven pom's seem over-engineered in comparison, and you only need a fraction of it in the `build.gradle`. (You don't even need any other files than that one, unless you are building multi-module projects.) Compare my original *pom.xml* with the *build.gradle* file in my accepted answer. They both do exactly the same thing...short of copying a few files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that because the Maven build file (`pom.xml`) had so many plugins in it, that I was thinking they were needed also in *Gradle*. That is a big mistake because Gradle's `build.gradle` file only need minimal plugin info. The rest is downloaded and used automagically.

In my case it only needed the Gradle version of [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/), the [**`gwt-gradle-plugin`**](https://github.com/jiakuan/gwt-gradle-plugin) plugin.

The corrected and hugely simplified **`build.gradle`** becomes:

```
// This must be before plugins!
buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.8"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.8.2'
}

apply plugin: 'gwt-compiler'
...
```

Now you can just run:
**`gradle compileGwt --console verbose --info`**
and all files will be built in the **`./build`** directory.

Comment: It's been so long since last time I worked with Maven, I completely forgot it needs every single dependency of the dependency of the dependency explicitly written out! In fact, I'm not even sure it does, but this seems to imply so...